# Запись\считывание структуры из файла

Tags: структуры-данных, запись, c, файлы, c++

Подскажите, у меня имеется структура такого вида:

```
struct Item{
 int key;
 int release;
 char *info;
};
```

Как я могу ее записать в двоичный файл, а потом считать из файла?

В задании есть доп. требования:
чтение и запись выполнять через fread() и fwrite(), в которых должна быть указана реальная длина информации.
Что может подразумеваться под длинной информации?

Comment: такую структуру так просто нельзя записать в файл из-за поля info. Для него нужно указать длину. Хотя можно сделать и без длины, но тогда нужен ограничитель конца записи (к примеру, классический '\0').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним вызовом fread/fwrite, пожалуй не удастся, а парочкой можно.

```
 int write_str (Item *ps, FILE *f) { 
   struct Item s = *ps;  // не хочу менять оригинал (tread/signal safe?)
   char *t = s.info;
   int ls = (*((long *)(&s.info)) = strlen(t)), // тут запишем длину строки
       l = fwrite(&s, 1, sizeof(s), f),
       l2 = fwrite(t, 1, ls, f);

   return (l == sizeof(s) && l2 == ls) ? l + ls : -1;
 }
```

ну, а read аналогично -- 2 fread + strdup

```
   fread(&s, 1, sizeof(s), f);
   int l = *((long *)(&s.info));
   char *t[l + 1];
   ...
```

места мало

Comment: на некоторых системах (в частности Windows 64bit) размер указателя не равен, размеру long. См. http://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0012/

Comment: Это точно, но в данном случае непринципиально, поскольку и для Win-64 и для Linux (да, думаю и для почти всех популярных архитектур)  `sizeof(void *)` >= `sizeof(long)`. 

Более того, когда перед программистом встанет вопрос о переносимости его творений, IMHO он уже будет осведомлен об условной трансляции (`#ifdef` и т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Единственный правильный способ писать или передавать структуры куда-то это сериализовывать их. Записать структуру в файл прямо вот так в лоб может и прокатит, но вот считать её обратно - это вопрос. Если на том же хосте то проблемы в считывании и размещении в памяти скорее всего не будет, но в плане переносимости будет проблема.

Второй момент: записывать и считывать структуры в\из файл\файла с оговорками можно лишь в случае если струтура представляет в памяти неразрывый кусок.